# Selenium's .text just giving blank lines

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I've got this:

```
....
events = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("textblock")
for event in events:
    content = event.text
    print(content)
print(events)
```

This is the element, there are multiple. Each with different text:

```
<div class="textblock">example text</div>
```

Here's the output:

```
# one blank line for every item in list below...

# items below have been striped
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="", element="")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="", element="")> # and so on...
```

As you can see, instead of the text inside the `div`, I'm getting blank lines. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium will only return visible text. So, if this div is hidden in any way, or obstructed by another element, it will return an empty string because it is not visible. If you still need the text even if it's not visible, use javascript:

```
events = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("textblock")
for event in events:
    content = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].textContent;', event)
    print(content)
print(events)
```

Comment: Thanks! There's no way to do this without executing JavaScript, is there?

Comment: `get_attribute("innerHTML")` should solve your purpose. Check my Answer

Comment: @W.Reyna yeah whoops, you can just `event.get_attribute('textContent')` actually

Comment: @LucasTierney Thanks a ton. Can you help me to understand the difference between all the three `"text"`, `"innerHTML"` and `'textContent'` please?

Comment: `text` is a selenium command that as I said earlier will get the visible text (will also get styling such as a transform to UPPER). `innerHTML` will get any html inside your element, so if there's a span inside your element you will also get the html for that. `textContent` is just the text inside your element and no html tags, but does not care about visibility as it is a DOM property

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared your code block looks good to me. However I would suggest you to get a bit granular and instead of using `.text` method we can use **`get_attribute("innerHTML")`** method as follows :

```
....
events = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("textblock")
for event in events:
    content = event.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(content)
print(events)
```

Comment: `get_attribute('innerHTML')` will get more than just text if there are more elements within the element desired.